# File not found when installing from pip

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to solve an issue that I've found when trying to install a python package in Lubuntu 17.04.

The package is for python 3.5 64bits. It's called RawPy and depends on the LibRaw library. I have installed the LibRaw library but when trying to install RawPy, it is not able to find some files of the LibRaw installation:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo -H pip3 install rawpy
Collecting rawpy
  Using cached rawpy-0.9.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from rawpy)
Building wheels for collected packages: rawpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rawpy ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pyqrhjz2/rawpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp9a3kr8dtpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
  copying rawpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
  copying rawpy/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
  copying rawpy/enhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
  running build_ext
  building 'rawpy._rawpy' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-7CCmgg/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_HAS_LIBRAW_CONFIG_H=0 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c _rawpy.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_rawpy.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                   from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                   from _rawpy.cpp:482:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
   #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
    ^~~~~~~
  In file included from _rawpy.cpp:484:0:
  def_helper.h:1:28: fatal error: libraw_version.h: No such file or directory
   #include "libraw_version.h"
                              ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rawpy
  Running setup.py clean for rawpy
Failed to build rawpy
Installing collected packages: rawpy
  Running setup.py install for rawpy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pyqrhjz2/rawpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-byii91yd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
    copying rawpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
    copying rawpy/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
    copying rawpy/enhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/rawpy
    running build_ext
    building 'rawpy._rawpy' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-7CCmgg/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -D_HAS_LIBRAW_CONFIG_H=0 -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c _rawpy.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_rawpy.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from _rawpy.cpp:482:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^~~~~~~
    In file included from _rawpy.cpp:484:0:
    def_helper.h:1:28: fatal error: libraw_version.h: No such file or directory
     #include "libraw_version.h"
                                ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pyqrhjz2/rawpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-byii91yd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pyqrhjz2/rawpy/
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

I have checked and that missing files exist at usr/local/lib/libraw. Tried to add that route using ldconfig but that didn't work.

LibRaw do seems to be installed. When I write `ldconfig -p`, I get:

```
libraw1394.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw1394.so.11
libraw_r.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libraw_r.so.16
libraw_r.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw_r.so.16
libraw_r.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libraw_r.so
libraw.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libraw.so.16
libraw.so.16 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw.so.16
libraw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libraw.so
```

And indeed:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo apt install libraw-dev 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... 
Done libraw-dev is already the newest version (0.18.1-1). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

The locations of the file are these:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo find / -name libraw_version.h
/usr/include/libraw/libraw_version.h
/usr/local/include/libraw/libraw_version.h
/home/lubuntu/libraw/libraw/libraw_version.h
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

The third location is the download folder of the source code from GitHub. I also compiled the last version of the code but it didnt work

Is there any way to explicitly tell pip to look in certain path for dependencies? I have even thought oh changing the source to explicitly tell the path but I don't think that is the proper fix.

Someone any idea?

Comment: Is the **development** package installed (`libraw-dev`)? The runtime library package(s) do not provide headers.

Comment: Yes, it's installed. See updated info above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of rawpy.

I'm not sure about the specific issue you have but I released a new version recently which provides binary packages (wheels) for Linux (in addition to Windows and macOS), so no more compilation or manual installation of libraw needed. Just reinstall rawpy and it should work out of the box.

Comment: Really grateful for this! I've checked it out and the wheels have worked with no problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`echo "/usr/local/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/99local.conf`

followed by `sudo ldconfig`.

This is tken from the  [installation instructions for rawpy.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rawpy/0.1.0)

Comment: Yes, I had previously tried that with both `"usr/local/lib"` and `"usr/local/lib/libraw"`. None of them seems to change anything